# y-axis limits of radar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, limits, radar-chart, ggproto

I have used the following example for my question: 
http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~lepennec/R/Radar/RadarAndParallelPlots.html

```
mtcarsscaled <- as.data.frame(lapply(mtcars, ggplot2:::rescale01))
mtcarsscaled$model <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcarsmelted <- reshape2::melt(mtcarsscaled)

coord_radar <- function (theta = "x", start = 0, direction = 1) 
{
  theta <- match.arg(theta, c("x", "y"))
  r <- if (theta == "x") 
    "y"
  else "x"
  ggproto("CordRadar", CoordPolar, theta = theta, r = r, start = start, 
          direction = sign(direction),
          is_linear = function(coord) TRUE)
}

plot <- ggplot(mtcarsmelted, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = model, color = model), fill = NA, size = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_line(aes(group = model, color = model), size = 2) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = rel(0.8)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = rel(0.8)),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(ncol=2)) +
  coord_radar()

print(plot)
```

How can I define limits for the y axis? Currently, the lowest value will be in the middle of the radar plot and zero will not be indicated. I would like zero to be in the middle rather than the middle/center of the plot to be the lowest value.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out it simply worked with

```
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10), breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

... but I had to change the values into as.numeric beforehand.